Protocol error while using Pepperl Fuchs OBD30M-R2000
I am trying to use the  OBD30M-R2000 from Pepperl using the ROS package provided by them. The sensor is connecting successfully but not returning any data, and hence is throwing a protocol error. The sensor is also giving data on the PactWare app that P&F recommends.

Turns out not R2000 LiDAR support ROS (Or even reading data from the sensor). Only OMD series allows this, and OBD does not.
